# Where can I maintain the detail part data in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently I am developing a mvc4 application, where I have a Header and Detail. The header may have multiple details. Example my detail part is contact details.

In that I can add multiple contacts, while adding contacts currently I am saving these values
in session. When i am saving the header part, I get the details from session and assign the object to header and then saved into the db.

So my question is where i can maintain the detail part in MVC?

Comment: Hard to get help with no code. Please read this post: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx , it will help you with formulating excellent questions here - which, in the end, only helps you get better answers. People do want to help. Help them help you.

Comment: Thanks Travis i will follow your link....

Comment: You seem to have [asked two questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744982/how-can-i-maintain-the-detail-part-data-in-mvc) on this topic - the most recent one has closed. Please only ask a question once, otherwise it creates work.